# how can i match two consecutive words that both start with capital letters?

Tags: perl

I want to match first and last name.

e.g. Robert Still, the words can be preceeded and followed by whitespaces however the string can only contain two words.

```
' Robert Still    ' = true
' Robert     Still ' = true
'e  Robert Still  4 ' = false
```

this is the code that i tried

```
m/^\s*[A-Z].*[a-z]\s*[A-Z].*[a-z]\s*$/
```

Comment: m/^\s*[A-Z].*[a-z]\s*[A-Z].*[a-z]\s*$/

Comment: @user2663377 - does my answer achieve what you wanted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; 

my @names = ('Robert Still', '    Robert Still', 'Robert Still    ', '4 Robert Still 2', 'Robert e Still');

foreach (@names){
    if ($_ =~ /(^\s*[A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z]\w+\s*$)/){
        print "'$_' : true\n" 
    }
    else {
        print "'$_' : false\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
'Robert Still' : true
'    Robert Still' : true
'Robert Still    ' : true
'4 Robert Still 2' : false
'Robert e Still' : false
```

Regex explained:

- `^` Start of line
- `\s*` 0 to infinite times [greedy] Whitespace [\t \r\n\f\v]
- Char class `[A-Z]` matches: A-Z A character range between Literal A and Literal Z
- `\w+` 1 to infinite times [greedy] Word character [a-zA-Z_\d]
- `\s+` 1 to infinite times [greedy] Whitespace [\t \r\n\f\v]
- Char class `[A-Z]` matches: A-Z A character range between Literal A and Literal Z
- `\w+` 1 to infinite times [greedy] Word character [a-zA-Z_\d]
- `\s*` 0 to infinite times [greedy] Whitespace [\t \r\n\f\v]
- `$` End of line

Comment: maybe you should match at least one spacing mark between the two names: ^\s*[A-Z]\w+\s+[A-Z]\w+\s*$ otherwise it would match 'RobertStill'

Answer (score 0):

```
/^ \s* \p{Lu}\S+ \s+ \p{Lu}\S+ \s* \z/x
```